# How to enable reactivityTransform in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want to enable Vue 3 experimental feature `reactivityTransform` in Nuxt 3 (3.0.0-rc.3). I've tried the solution provided [here](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/2591#issuecomment-1005579830), but it did not work and I did get the following error:

```
Type '{ vue: { reactivityTransform: true; }; }' is not assignable to type 'UserConfig'.
```

Here is my `nuxt.config.ts` file:

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    vue: {
      reactivityTransform: true
    }
  },
});
```

Any idea about what am I doing wrong? How can I enable `reactivityTransform` in Nuxt 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently in the current version of Nuxt 3 (3.0.0-rc.3), instead of modifing the vite config in the `nuxt.config` file, we should add an experimental proprety; The following code enabled `reactivityTransform` in Nuxt 3:

```js
// nuxt.config.ts
import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt";

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  experimental: {
    reactivityTransform: true
  },
});
```

Here is the [related link](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/pull/3737).